# problem merging jupyter notebooks with nbdime

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook, git-merge

I am trying to merge a branch `testing` with an edited version of a jupyter notebook into my `master` branch with another version of the same notebook. I have edited the files in both branches in the same line respectively. So I would expect a merge conflict.

That is what the file on master branch looks like:

[image]

That is what the file on testing branch looks like:

[image]

`git checkout master` and then `git merge testing` is telling me, there is a merge conflict and I need to resolve it on my own - ok ,fine.
git also tells me that I am in a state of merging, so the next step would be to open the mentioned file on my master branch. And there I would expect to see the conflict. However, I just see the normal Notebook from the master branch. So I am not even able to resolve the conflict.

I would expect to see something like this (from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlYvvCT5Xqs&t=1s)):

[image]

`git diff` however works as expected and shows me the following diff:

[image]

So what is wrong with my git/nbdime? Why can't I properly merge jupyter Notebooks? Any ideas?
I also have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544667/how-to-use-nbdime-diffing-and-merging-for-jupyter-notebooks-in-git-bash) describing how I have set up nbdime and git respectively (because I am wondering why I can't use the nbdime commands in bash).